# Is there any better way to define ExecuteAsync<T> in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I am new to restSharp and trying to execute an API test using asynchronous way, below code is running without any issue, can someone help me  to update the code such a way that it can handle any error?

```
public void Test()
    { 
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://reqres.in/");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/api/users?page=2", Method.Get);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        var results = getAsyncGetData<UserList>(client, request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Assert.AreEqual(results.Data.per_page,6);

    }

    private static async Task<RestResponse<T>> getAsyncGetData<T>(RestClient client,RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {  
       RestResponse<T> response = await client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request);
        return response;}
```

Comment: What are you invoking the Test method from? This will execute successfully in most cases, although it would be highly preferable to make Test async as well.

Comment: Voting to close until there is an actual question, not just _"help me to update the code such a way that it can handle any error"_.

Comment: What do you mean by handle any error? Handle exceptions? Handle error response codes?

Have you checked out https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html